# Using The Input Value Instead Of The First Statement Of A Loop In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to understand the insertion sort algorithm. I want to use an input button and diagram. When the user writes a number then click the button, my page will create random values. I found some snippets on the internet but they use `i = 0`. I want to use my input value instead of `i = 0`. How can I do it?

A part of my index.html:

```
<div id="buttons">
       <a class="button" id="butonInsert"  href="javascript://">insertion sort</a>
       <a class="button" id="butonReset"  href="javascript://">Reset</a>
       <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="blabla">
       <button onclick="reset()"></button>
```

A part of my script.js:

```
function reset() {
 for (i=0; i<50; ++i) {
        data[i] = ~~(i*160/50);
    }
    for (i=data.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        var ridx = ~~( Math.random() * ( data.length ) );
        data.swap(i, ridx);
    }
    var tb = $("#sortPanel");
    tb.empty();
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    for (i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
        tr.append("<td  id='b"+i+"'>" +
                  "<div class='cc' style='height: "+data[i]+"px;'>" +
                  "</div></td>");
    }
    tb.append(tr);
    resetted = true;
}
```

Comment: Please include a question statement. A desired output and actual output in the question.

Comment: $('#myNumber').val() should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do but if you just want to use an input's value you can easily get it with javascript and use it instead of `i=0`.

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById("myNumber").value ;
```

Then in your `for` statements :

```
for (var i = inputValue ; i < data.length; ++i) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementbyId('myNumber').value`. This might work.

Comment: i used but i didnt work.Also i dont know how can i use my input value in my reset function as a start value instead of i=0